# Replace multiple spaces in a string

Tags: php, regex

how to change spaces more than one into underscore, but not change single spaces?

**First:**

`21   Facebook Inc               6                  860,000`

**Result:**

`21_Facebook Inc_6_860,000`

Comment: Surely you didn't try anything? You tagged the post with regular expressions but couldn't come with something?

Comment: At first I tried this, but all the whitespace was erased...

Comment: preg_replace( "(/\s+/g, ' ')", "   ", $txt);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should used `preg_replace` function. for more details read [PHP `preg_replace` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Here is the example

```
$string="21   Facebook Inc               6                  860,000";
$string = preg_replace('/[\t\n\r\0\x0B]/', '', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/([\s])\1+/', '_', $string);
print_r($string);
```

You can check your desired [output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f7a3ee546a251e70413d24c964c2dbf37211c7e)

Comment: Thanks, this works :D

Comment: @IrvanAhmadPrasetya your welcome. you should accept or up-vote the correct answer because in future your question is helpful or value-able for other users

Answer (score 2):

You could use `{2,}` to get only 2 or more spaces :

```
$str = '21   Facebook Inc               6                  860,000';
$str = preg_replace('~([ ]{2,})~', '_', $str);
echo $str; // 21_Facebook Inc_6_860,000
```

Comment: Thanks this way also works (y)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern

```
$string = "21   Facebook Inc               6                  860,000";
$result = preg_replace('/(\s{2,})/', '_', $string);
echo result;
```

**Note:**

- `\s`   - matches whitespace characters
- `{2,}` - matches between 2 and unlimited times

Comment: Thanks, for answer, this work (y)